# handle button clicks in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, buttonclick, android-dialogfragment

I have Fragment that extends DialogFragment and I have a custom layout for it which contains two edittexts and two buttons - ok and cancel. My dialog displays just fine, using the onCreateView method for specifying the layout, but I don't know how to handle button clicks. Inside the onCreateView method, button.setOnClickListener doesn't work. This may have a simple solution, but I am stuck for several hours. I would very much appreciate an advice or example code.

P.S I don't want to use AlertDialog, because in this case when clicking on the ok button, the dialog automatically dismisses itself, and I can't do a validation on the edittext's (example: when the user presses ok button and the edittext's are empty I don't want the dialog to disappear). That is way I went with the option for creating a custom dialog and easily manage the buttons behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do along these lines

```
Dialog dl = mDialogFragment.getDialog();
Button btn = dl.findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thank u. I already found a solution like this.       buttonOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
              

               }
             }
         });  but maybe your solution works too. Thx anyway!

Comment: `getDialog()` returns null!

Answer (score 10):

This is the code for a Dialog I'm using (the actual GUI for the dialog is defined in the layout resource confirm_dialog.xml):

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static String TAG = "Confirm Dialog";

    public interface ConfirmDialogCompliant {
        public void doOkConfirmClick();
        public void doCancelConfirmClick();
    }

    private ConfirmDialogCompliant caller;
    private String message;

    public ConfirmDialog(ConfirmDialogCompliant caller, String message){
        super();
        this.caller = caller;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_confirm)).setText(message);
        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ok_confirm_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
                caller.doOkConfirmClick();
            }
        });
        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_confirm_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
                caller.doCancelConfirmClick();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

The dialog is created with the following lines

```
confirm_dialog = new ConfirmDialog(this, message);
confirm_dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), ConfirmDialog.TAG);
```

The interface definition is used to assure that the caller (Fragment or Activity) implements the methods to handle the events thrown by the controller. That is, a Fragment or Activity calling this dialog must implement the given interface.
Maybe there is a better solution but this is the one I figured out. Hope it helps!

Comment: setting the onClickListener like this didn't work for me. It gave me errors. I found a solution to my problem, and wrote it as a comment to the first answer. Thank you for your response anyway.

Comment: This works if you're inflating your layout from an xml resource. If you're creating your layout programmatically then you got ta call setOnClickListener on your Button reference.

Comment: Yes, I also inflate a layout from an xml resource in the onCreateView method. The problem I was having was that: myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {} was giving me error, so the solution was using myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}. I don't know why it did not recognize my listener that way, but it did..

Comment: This is the same solution I tought of, but I hesistate to make it this way because Fragment should have default constructors. In addition, I don't know how to put the Interface "Caller" in a Args Bundle. Any Idea ?

Comment: This will crash with a NPE after your fragment is re-instantiated (after a config change or being destroyed in the background for eg) and you click on a button.  The default constructor is called when the fragment manager re-creates a fragment.

Answer (score 8):

here is an example to handel a cancel button click on a dialog from the FragmentDialog class:

i used android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment { 
    public MyDialogFragment(){}     
    public static String TAG = "info Dialog";
    Button btn;   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, container);
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(STYLE_NO_TITLE);
        btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.close_dialog_btn_info_layout);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }





}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to let your custom `DialogFragment` class implement `OnClickListener`. Then you just `setOnClickListener` for whatever views you want to handle clicks on and catch the clicks in `onClick`.

```
// 1. implement OnClickListener
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null);

        // 2. set click listeners on desired views 
        view.findViewById(R.id.my_view_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.my_view_2).setOnClickListener(this);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view)
                // ...
        return builder.create();
    }   

    // 3. capture the clicks and respond depending on which view
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.my_view_1:
                // do something
                break;
            case R.id.my_view_2:
                // do something
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy in activity but in DialogFragment we do some more codes.

Inside the DialogFragment class do your rutin findView on `onActivityCreated`method

```
btn_ocak = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cal_ocak);
    btn_subat = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cal_subat);
    btn_mart = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cal_mart);
    btn_nisan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cal_nisan);


 btn_ocak.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_subat.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_mart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_nisan.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Implement onClick OnClickListener to your class

```
public class CalendarPopUp extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

and do what you want inside onClick method, by doing these we activated the onClick events of our views

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_cal_ocak:
            seciliAy = "Ocak";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_subat:
            seciliAy = "Subat";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_mart:
            seciliAy = "Mart";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_nisan:
            seciliAy = "Nisan";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_mayis:
            seciliAy = "Mayıs";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_haziran:
            seciliAy = "Haziran";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_temmuz:
            seciliAy = "Temmuz";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_agustos:
            seciliAy = "Agustos";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_eylul:
            seciliAy = "Eylül";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_ekim:
            seciliAy = "Ekim";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_kasim:
            seciliAy = "Kasım";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_cal_aralik:
            seciliAy = "Aralık";
            setMonthOnShare(seciliAy);
            mCallback.onSelectedData(seciliAy);
            dismiss();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and if you wonder how to pass values follow these step
[clike_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526866/return-values-from-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 1):

or

```
class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
   public View.OnClickListener onButtonOk;
   public EditText edit_text;

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(builder.getContext());
       View view = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
       Button buttonOK = view.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
       edit_text = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
       buttonOk.setOnClickListener(onButtonOk);
       builder.setView(view);

       return builder.create();
   }

}


// use
final MyDialog dialog=new MyDialog();
dialog.onButtonOk=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), dialog.edit_text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),null);
```