# Return values from DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I am doing task in which I need to show a dialog after clicking on `EditText`. In that dialog I show contents with `RadioButton`s using `RecyclerView`.

Now, what I want to do is, after selecting RadioButton (content which is in the RecyclerView) from dialog, it should return value of that content and then dialog should be dismissed.

To generate a dialog I've used a `DialogFragment`.

As I'm new in android development, I am totally confused and unable to find the solution.

Comment: post your problem code..

Comment: @Mohit Actually, There is no error in code, I unable to figure out how to implement this.

Comment: I've classes as ldDialog.java, ldListAdapter.java And code to display dialog is " editTextLeadSource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchDialog("LeadSource");
            }
        });"

Answer (score 35):

Because your dialog is a `DialogFragment` you can use two things

> 1. If you are starting the dialog from a `Activity`, you can use an interface

- create an interface

  ```
  public interface ISelectedData {
      void onSelectedData(String string);
  }
  ```
- implement an interface in your Activity

  ```
  public class MyActivity implements ISelectedData {

      .....

      @Override 
      public void onSelectedData(String myValue) {
          // Use the returned value
      }
  }
  ```
- in your Dialog, attach the interface to your Activity

  ```
  private ISelectedData mCallback;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);

      try {
          mCallback = (ISelectedData) activity;
      }
      catch (ClassCastException e) {
          Log.d("MyDialog", "Activity doesn't implement the ISelectedData interface");
      }
  }
  ```
- when returning the value to Activity, just call in your Dialog

  ```
  mCallback.onSelectedData("myValue");
  ```

  Check the [example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) on the Android developer site.

> 2. If you are starting the dialog from a `Fragment`, you can use `setTargetFragment(...)`

- starting the Dialog

  ```
  MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
  dialog.setTargetFragment(this, Constants.DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE);
  dialog.show(fragmentManager, Constants.DIALOG);
  ```
- returning the value from the Dialog

  ```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString(Constants.MY_VALUE, "MyValue");

  Intent intent = new Intent().putExtras(bundle);

  getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

  dismiss();
  ```
- getting the value in Fragment

  ```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == Constants.DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE) {

          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

              if (data.getExtras().containsKey(Constants.MY_VALUE)) {

                  String myValue = data.getExtras().getString(Constants.MY_VALUE);

                  // Use the returned value
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: And How can I set click event to the contents of the recyclerview which is within that dialog, so that on that click event i get values and set to the Edittextview.??

Comment: If you need a click listener to your RecyclerView's row you can use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif). Similar set listeners to views inside the row or use the answer with 277 upvotes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick).

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will try this solutions...@Marko

Comment: One more thing, your code for getting values, should I add it to onClick event ?

Comment: Which example, the second one? You have to override the `onActivityResult` method in your `Fragment` and the value will be automaticaly returned. If you want to return the value in onClick, you have to call `getTargetFragment().onActivityResult()...` to return the value.

Comment: @Marco Once,I clicked textView in recyclerView it should close the dialog. Here,if I put dismiss() in onClick() event, It gives me NullPointerException.

Comment: @PeterParker I do not know what happens because I do not have / see your code. Step through the code with a debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: I already waste 2 days on this but now your way save my more time on it. Thanks alot

Comment: I'm a little confused: if we could trigger fragment `onActivityResult`, then why don't we also use it in first situation. like `if (getActivity() != null) getActivity().onActivityResult( /*...*/ )` ?

Comment: Ah, I see -- the `FragmentActivity.onActivityResult` method is protected, so you cannot call that from a (Dialog)Fragment.