# how to add items to listview through alert dialog box

Tags: java, android, xml

I am stuck in a project. I need to add items to my ListView through alert dialog box. like 1st item will act as a heading and when it is selected a dialog box will open and the value will be added as sub item of that `ListView`. I will attach pictures just the I want them to be. Please if anyone can help.

below is the picture of ODK app.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxOXz.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxOXz.jpg

Comment: Sorry pictures were not uploaded back then

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial

Comment: you have to maintain a list of item locally. Make a model class with getter setter and this class will contain header and sub header. OnClick alert dialog ok button get the value from alert dialog edit text and then set the model class then just set you adapter and notify data change.

Comment: how to get the value which is written in alert dialog box.

Comment: Are you asking for how to get the value from the alert dialog into the fragment to be passed into the listview? If so, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526866/return-values-from-dialogfragment